# Jmeter script of post request still running successfully in case mandatory parameter is deleted

Tags: jmeter

I am new in Jmeter and doing some R & D 
I recorded a signup scenario where some fields are mandatory to give like username, customerid etc.

I playback that script that run successfully which is fine but if i replace the value of customerid by blank and run again, the test plan still running without errors

In my opinion there should thrown an error if customerid is not valid

[image: Result]

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter doesn't automatically check response body for any errors and it treats all HTTP responses with codes `2xx` and `3xx` as successful.

If you need to validate an error message go for [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) - it can conditionally fail sampler basing on presence or absence of some search pattern in the response.

[image: Response Assertion in work]

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article to learn more about using assertions in your JMeter test

Comment: Thanks for a quick response.let me try how it will validate on parameters

Comment: Now The thing is how I validate that customerID parameter as shown in screenshot by Assertion element

Comment: If you need to validate the parameter use [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion), the relevant code will be `if (!ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().getArgumentsAsMap().get("customerId").equals("foo")) { Failure = true; }` (replace `foo` with expected value. See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details on Beanshell scripting in JMeter

Comment: Thanks for the solutions ,after some updates, it works for me. Now I will also test it for Parameterization .